# Should i stop playing this game

Tags: halal-haram, game

There is a game called war thunder in which is a sticker(a semi stripped woman) a player can apply to his tank.
When i play the game sometimes i see people using that sticker.People even make penis drawing out of 0 digits.
Am i responsible here?
Should  stop playing that game because of those people?

Answer (score 1):

*Accidentaly* seeing a sticker of a half naked woman or human genital isn't haram, but it is when it's completely avoidable and predictable. So in this case it's avoidable and predictable, so you're kind of responsible if you see that sticker.